# Give 'full control' to a list but restrict item editing

Tags: list, permissions

How can I give a sharepoint group full control of a list but at the same time not allow them to edit items? (giving them Read access is not sufficient).

Comment: This is not possible the way that you describe it but there are other possibilities.  What functionality, specifically, are you looking to give them beyond read?

Comment: Hi Dave, I want them to have full control of the list but at the same time only be able to read items no, editing, deleting etc- is there a way to do this?

Comment: That, by definition, is not Full Control. Look into the solution that lgaud lists below and see if the permission levels offer the granularity you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Create a new permission level (Full Control, Read, Contribute are some of the built in permission levels) that gives exactly the permissions you do want, and assign the group that permission level for the list. You can see more information about the permissions & permission  levels here: http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/windows-sharepoint-services-help/permission-levels-and-permissions-HA010100149.aspx